# Faltou traduzir uma parte da aba de votos para reabrir

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Tem uma parte do perfil que não tá traduzida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O caminho para chegar nessa tela é: Seu perfil > Votos > Reabrir

Comment: E o que seria esse `(excluídos)` abaixo de _reopen_? Tem isso abaixo de todos os itens nessa aba, entretanto nem todos estão excluídos.

Comment: O `(excluídos)` é porque a ação foi concretizada: a pergunta foi reaberta e seu voto é considerado "excluído" (da lista de pendentes).

Comment: Esse é um dos *vários* casos em que uma palavra, ou trecho, simplesmente não está no nosso sistema de tradução. Aí eu tenho que ver com os devs pra ver por que ela não está lá.

Comment: Adicionada tag internacionalização a partir dessa informação do Gabe.